# Solving the PDE $xu_{x} + 2yu_{y} = 3u, u(x,y,0) = g(x,y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I was trying to solve the PDE:

$xu_{x} + 2yu_{y} = 3u$ with $u(x,y,0) = g(x,y)$

I thought of using method of characteristics

So the initial curve looks like $x = a, y=b , z = g(a,b)$

with

$\frac{dx}{ds} = x, \frac{dy}{ds} = 2y , \frac{dz}{ds} = 3z$

$x(0)  =a, y(0) = b, z(0) = g(a,b)$

implying $x = ae^s , y = be^{2s} , z = g(a,b) e^{3s}$

So we have $xy = ab e^{3s}$

implying $e^{3s} = \frac{xy}{ab}$

so that $z = g(a,b) \frac{xy}{ab}$

but I think it is incorrect as i think that it doesnot satisfy the initial conditions.

Any help would be nice!

Comment: The third variable amounts another equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xu_x+2yu_y=3u\tag 1$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{2y}=\frac{du}{3u}=ds$$
First characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{2y}$ :
$$\frac{y}{x^2}=c_1$$
Second characteristic equation from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{3u}$ :
$$\frac{u}{x^3}=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE $(1)$ on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ :

$\frac{u}{x^3}=F\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)$
$$u(x,y)=x^3F\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to some boundary condition.

The wording of the question makes appear a dummy variable $t$ . Thus the general solution of equation $(1)$ is :
$$u(x,y,t)=x^3\Phi\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\:,\:t\right) \tag 2$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables, to be determined according to some boundary and initial conditions.

The specified initial condition $u(x,y,0)=g(x,y)$ implies only one equation :
$$g(x,y)=x^3\Phi\left(\frac{y}{x^2}\:,\:0\right)$$
which is not sufficient for the function $\Phi$ to be determined.